Didn't find Login page without declaration of _Layout in asp.net core mvc 6,7
I've a fully custom _Layout page in location "~/Views/Shared/".
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
<!-- dashbaord layout -->
<!-- dashboard side bar -->
<!-- dashboard header -->
<!-- dashboard body -->
     @RenderBody()
<!-- dashboard footer -->
}
else
{
     RenderBody();
        
}
<script src="~/js/index.js"></script>

@if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
{
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
}

I've added Identity in order to add authentication and authorization in my project. I've applied condition in _Layout page and [Authorize] annotation in Controller to authenticated site.
[Authorize]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        
        return View();
    }
}

But without declaring "_Layout" in login page the page didn't appear.
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<div class="row">

And if I add "_Layout" in login page default navigation bar appear as top bar in login page which is not in my "_Layout".
enter image description here
How can I run Login page without this Top bar?

You could try setting the Layout = null; in view OR create separate view for the login and register page which does not require authtication.in your _ViewStart.cshtml, set the default layout to your custom _Layout.cshtml. this will make sure that every view that does not explicitly set its Layout property will use _Layout.cshtml by default.
create  _PublicLayout.cshtml in your Views/Shared directory:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - App Name</title>
    <!-- Styles, Scripts, etc. -->
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <!-- scripts -->
</body>
</html>

_ViewStart.cshtml:
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

Login.cshtml:
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PublicLayout.cshtml"; 
}

<!-- login page code -->

For more detail about Layout you could refer this document:
Layout in ASP.NET Core
